# Not full auto completion for WxPython in PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, wxpython, miniconda

In this example:

```
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='Hello, World!')
```

Auto completion work for `wx.Frame` but don't work in parentheses. So when i'm write `par` it did't auto-complete for `parent=`.

I tried google it but didn't find answer.

I'm using PyCharm Community 2019.3 . Miniconda3 with Python 3.7.4 . wxpython 4.0.4

> Could you please navigate to Frame definition by Right Click on it -
>   Go To - Declaration or Usages. What parameters does its constructor
>   have?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        """
        Frame()
        Frame(parent, id=ID_ANY, title=EmptyString, pos=DefaultPosition, size=DefaultSize, style=DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, name=FrameNameStr)

        A frame is a window whose size and position can (usually) be changed
        by the user.
        """
```

It shows a `\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\wx\core.pyi` file with `Frame` class inside.

Comment: Could you please navigate to `Frame` definition by `Right Click on it - Go To - Declaration or Usages`. What parameters does its constructor have?

Comment: I will add it to question. @user2235698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the C++ `wxFrame` constructor is overloaded then we need to use `*args, **kw` to be able to match either overload. However, the two overloads are given at the start of the docstring, so you can still get the info that way, and more details are present in the documentation at https://docs.wxpython.org/.

There are some plans to improve the code that is generated into the `.pyi` files, including using type hint annotations and the `typing.overload` decorator, but it may be awhile before that is done.